# What is the meaning of the blue line and the green line in MySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench, erd

[image: Mysql workbench screenshot]

As shown in the figure, the Country table is combined with the City table by the green line, and the City table is combined with the Address table by the blue line. I can't figure out what's the meaning of the two kind of lines.

Comment: Seems fairly obvious if you look at what is blue and what is green

Comment: The similarly coloured columns may be a clue..

Comment: @P.Salmon ahhh...I think I intangibly know the answer, but I would like a more official conclusion.

Comment: If you want an "official" answer you need to ask Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connections show relationships (foreign keys). That should be clear.

When you hover with the mouse over a table figure, all connections are highlighted which either go out from or come in to that table.

Outgoing connections, that is, foreign keys defined on that table, which reference a different table are shown in green.

Incoming connections, that is, foreign keys defined in another table, which end on the current table are colored blue.

The referenced fields are colored the same way as their associated relationship.

Currently table `city` is active, so the foreign key from `city.country_id` to `country.country_id` is colored green (it's an outgoing connection). Table `address` has defined a foreign key to city, which is shown in blue. Now hover `address` and you will see that the connection color to `city` switches from blue to green.